# SELECT does not return numeric value

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, group-by

I have a table 'books'. For simplicity, here are 3 columns:

```
name(text) | new(boolean) | press(text)
```

I need to select publishing house(press), which has most new books.
I don't understand why Access shows "Syntax error".

```
SELECT press, COUNT(new) AS [Number of new books]
FROM books
WHERE new = TRUE
GROUP BY press
HAVING COUNT(new) = 
  SELECT MAX(s) 
  FROM 
  (   SELECT COUNT(new) AS s, press 
      FROM books
      WHERE new = TRUE
      GROUP BY press
  )
```

If I write only the second part:

```
  SELECT MAX(s) 
  FROM 
  (   SELECT COUNT(new) AS s, press 
      FROM books
      WHERE new = TRUE
      GROUP BY press
  )
```

It returns correct value (5)

If I write only 1st part with condition `= 5`, it's good.

```
SELECT press, COUNT(new) AS [Number of new books]
FROM books
WHERE new = TRUE
GROUP BY press
HAVING COUNT(new) = 5
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second query should be enclosed with parenthesis

```
SELECT press, COUNT(new) AS [Number of new books]
FROM books
WHERE new = TRUE
GROUP BY press
HAVING COUNT(new) = 
(
  SELECT MAX(s) 
  FROM 
  (   SELECT COUNT(new) AS s, press 
      FROM books
      WHERE new = TRUE
      GROUP BY press
  )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You already have an aggregate (`GROUP BY`) query which returns the count of new books per `press`.  Use that as a subquery and take the `TOP 1` row after ordering by the count in descending order.

```
SELECT TOP 1
    sub.press,
    sub.CountOfNew AS [Number of new books]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            press,
            COUNT(*) AS CountOfNew
        FROM books
        WHERE [new] = TRUE
        GROUP BY press
    ) AS sub
ORDER BY sub.CountOfNew DESC
```

Note, if multiple `press`es are tied for the maximum `[Number of new books]`, this query will return all the ties.  (But then so will your original approach.)  If you only want one of those ties, include a unique field (such as the primary key) in the `ORDER BY`.